# Connecting asp.net with MS access 2007 in VS 2010

Tags: asp.net, database, ms-access-2007

I have created a small table of student info in MS Access 2007. The table name is "stdinfo" and fields are rollno,sname,sfather,address.
Now i want to display the table fields in asp.net application.

code behind code is

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:|Users|mac|Desktop|db.accdb;";
            OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from stdinfo";
            cmd.Connection = cn;
            cn.Open();
            rolllbl.Text = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery());
            cn.Close();
        }
```

and aspx code is

```
<p>
        <asp:Label ID="rolllbl" runat="server" Text="RollNo."></asp:Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </p>
    <p>
        &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="namelbl" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;</p>
    <p>
        <asp:Label ID="fnamelbl" runat="server" Text="Fname"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </p>
    <p>
        <asp:Label ID="addlbl" runat="server" Text="Address"></asp:Label>
    </p>
```

I did not wish to write the connection string in web config file. I am using VS 2010.

Is there any thing i need to add in the code behind ? the code is not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:|Users|mac|Desktop|db.accdb;";
        OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * from stdinfo";
        cmd.Connection = cn;
        cn.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());  // temporary storing data in a data table
        cn.Close();

     // Now assign the values to the label
           rolllbl.Text = dt.Rows[0]["ColumnName"].ToString();
           namelbl.Text = dt.Rows[0]["ColumnName"].ToString();
           fnamelbl.Text = dt.Rows[0]["ColumnName"].ToString();
           addlbl.Text = dt.Rows[0]["ColumnName"].ToString();               

            // OR  If you query returns multiple rows then use gridview 

        gv.DataSource = dt;
        gv.DataBind();  // binding grid   

    }
```

`ExecuteNonQuery` method returns the no. of rows affected, You will not get anything by converting into a string.
Also you can also use a gridview control

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" >
     <Columns>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="ColumnName" TextField="Roll No" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="ColumnName" TextField="Name" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="ColumnName" TextField="First Name" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="ColumnName" TextField="Address" />
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

Output:
Roll NO | Name | First Name | Address
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply...
When to use a datareader, datatable, dataadapter, dataset ?? I am realy confused ? plz help

Comment: @Tuhin it depends upon our need. DataReader is mainly used to retrieve data. DataTable is used to store data in memory.DataAdapter is used to perform all operatoins (Read,Write,Update,Delete) and DataSet is an in-memoery database or a collection of datatables. DataSet consists of multiple datatables. Read this post http://wfjanjua.blogspot.com/2012/01/when-to-use-datareader-dataset-adapter.html

Comment: So in your answer you have used datatable to store the student info in the memory (stack/heap) and then used label control or gridview control to display the data ... is that so??
Now further if i need to perform add/update/delete operations on the data then should i still use datatable or simply switch to dataadapter ??? and can i use data adapter along with gridview ??

Comment: @Tuhin yes you are right. DataTable is a different thing, It is only used to store data, while dataadapter act as a bridge between the database and the application.  You can also perform all the operation using SqlCommand object. It has many overload like ExecuteNonQuery is used to insert,update data and different methods, you can explore it on msdn. Also if this answer is helpful to you then remember to mark it as your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Welcome to ASP.NET!
    </h2>
    <p>
        To learn more about ASP.NET visit <a href="http://www.asp.net" title="ASP.NET Website">www.asp.net</a>.
    </p>
    <p>
        You can also find <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=152368&amp;clcid=0x409"
            title="MSDN ASP.NET Docs">documentation on ASP.NET at MSDN</a>.
    </p>

    <p>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        <Columns>          
        <asp:BoundField DataField="rollno" HeaderText="Roll" />          
        <asp:BoundField DataField="sname" HeaderText="Student Name" />          
        <asp:BoundField DataField="sfather" HeaderText="Fathers Name" />          
        <asp:BoundField DataField="address" HeaderText="Address" />      
        </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </p>
</asp:Content>
```

codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\mac\\Desktop\\db.accdb;"; 
            OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString); 
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(); 
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from stdinfo";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = cn;
            cn.Open();
            OleDbDataReader reader ; 
            reader=cmd.ExecuteReader();  // temporary storing data in a data table 

            GridView1.DataSource = reader;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            reader.Close();
            cn.Close();
        }
```

things are perfect but the result is displayed, i.e., each column is displayed twice ? why ??

Comment: add  AutoGenrateColumn = "false" in your gridview. `<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenrateColumn = "false" >.....`