# How to add two radiobuttons and a total to a mdb database when submit button?

Tags: asp.net, ms-access

Hey there I need help with this assignment please I got a mdb database named Courses with one table named `Course1` with 4 fields

```
ID(AutoNumber),Alchamex1(Text) and Alchamex2(Text) Total(Text)
```

how do I had these selected values to a mdb database Thanks in advance!!!

```
If CheckBox1.Checked = True And CheckBox2.Checked = True Then   
    answerLbl.Text =( Double.Parse(Label1.Text)+ Double.Parse(Label2.Text)).ToString()
ElseIf CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
    answerLbl.Text =Label2.Text
ElseIf CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
    answerLbl.Text = Label1.Text
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic steps:

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection (connectionString);
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.Connection = connection;
cmd.CommandText= "INSERT INTO Table1(col1, col2) VALUES (@col1, @col2)";
cmd.Parameters.Add ("@col1", OleDbType.String).Value = valueToInsert;
...
cmd.ExecuteNonQUery();
```

Refer this:

[Inserting Records into a Microsoft Access Database with ASP.NET](http://www.codefixer.com/asp-net/tutorials/insert-records-access-database-2.asp)

[Connecting asp.net with MS access 2007 in VS 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041223/connecting-asp-net-with-ms-access-2007-in-vs-2010)

[INSERT from ASP.NET to MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459442/insert-from-asp-net-to-ms-access)